# Ruby launcher.rb not working

Tags: ruby

### Story

Hello, decided I'd try out Ruby. I got a link from the official Ruby website on how to learn major Ruby concepts in 10 minutes. [Link here](http://neurogami.com/content/neurogami-10_minutes_to_your_first_Ruby_app/)

The tutorial is straight forward and easy to understand. I understand what the code is supposed to do, it just doesn't work as intended.

### Information:

1. No I am not getting any errors in my console when I run it.
2. I am on Mac and using Aptana console
3. My **ruby --version :** `ruby 2.0.0p481 (2014-05-08 revision 45883) [universal.x86_64-darwin14]`

### Code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class Test
  def initialize app_map
    @app_map = app_map
  end
  def run file_name
    application = select_app file_name
    system "#{application} #{file_name}"
  end

  def select_app file_name
    ftype = file_type file_name
    @app_map[ ftype ]
  end
  def file_type file_name
    File.extname( file_name ).gsub(/^\./, '').downcase
  end
end

def help
  print " 
  You must pass in the path to the file to launch.

  Usage: #{__FILE__} target_file
" 
end

if ARGV.empty?
  help
  exit
end

app_map = {
  'html' => 'firefox',
  'rb' => 'gvim'
}

test = Test.new app_map
target = ARGV.join ' '
test.run target
```

*It may not be obvious but you can scroll down in the code box.*

### So what is this supposed to do?

```
$ ruby test.rb test.rb
```

To run it, you need to add 1 arguement. It can be *.rb or .html* (I've tried both). If it's a *.html* file the program is supposed to open it up in *firefox*, if it's a *.rb* it's supposed to open it with *gvim*.

### Question:

Why is it not working? What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you try to run gvim or firefox directly in the console? Are they in your PATH?

Comment: @FrankSchmitt you are right. I'm getting a "command not found" for both apps. How do I fix this?

Comment: You'll have to either use the complete path to your executable (usually, something like /Applications/Mozilla Firefox.app/MacOS/firefox), add a symlink to a directory in your PATH (e.g. /usr/local/bin) or add the directories to your PATH environment variable.

Comment: @FrankSchmitt yeah works if I add the complete path. However I had to change it to 'html' => 'open /Applications/Firefox.app'. gvim I changed it to  just vim. Go ahead and post the answer and I'll mark it as right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My terminal didn't recognize firefox app name. No error was returned when I started the program.

I had to specifiy the full path name:

```
'html' => 'open /Applications/Firefox.app'
```

And I changed `gvim` to `vim`

This solved the problem.